# Displaying images in a grid or backpack style in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, text, grid

I cant find out how to display images in grid style like a tf2 backpack with text on them, for example https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVTaJ.png
I have the images already i just need to help on making them fit together on a grid with text on the images.
Code: http://jsfiddle.net/w5dLvqjq/

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Seach backpacks</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: paste your html here or jsfiddle link. show some code please

Comment: give the width to wrapper div of image and float it left

Comment: @danish443 I dont have any code for it, im totally lost but ill post my site so far, its just a basic bootstrap site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated** Well you can style much and use position attribute to achieve that text above and below effect

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="image-grid">
      <div class="text-above"><p> Some Text Above</p></div>
      <div class="text-below"><p> Some Text Below</p></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="image-grid">
      <div class="text-above"><p> Some Text Above</p></div>
      <div class="text-below"><p> Some Text Below</p></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="image-grid">
      <div class="text-above"><p> Some Text Above</p></div>
      <div class="text-below"><p> Some Text Below</p></div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="image-grid">
      <div class="text-above"><p> Some Text Above</p></div>
      <div class="text-below"><p> Some Text Below</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Custom.css

```
.image-grid{
background-image:url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}

.text-above{

    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;

}

.text-below{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0;

}

.text-below p{
     margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap. Here the way you can play with it unless you know about col grid system you can check it from this url (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

On your body html part add this coding

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Responsive Image Grid</h1>

    <hr>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <br><br>

</div>
```

On your css add

```
.thumbnail {
    margin-bottom:7px;
}
```

Here the result you will get. ( http://www.bootply.com/EgguyY7Dfl )

Hope you learn something. :)

Comment: How would i add text on the img

Comment: @bbousq I don't get it.

Comment: @L-X answer this is not a good way to learn because adding text like that. Messy layout i can say.

Comment: @Fiido , have you read the question , he is asking how to display text over image , and my code focuses on that but your grid is simple and cleaner ;-)